# Strange Freeze on My MacBook Pro 15.4" 2.0GHZ (A1150 / MA600LL) & No Sound After Boot

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, performance, macos

I have a MacBook Pro 15" A1150 (MA600LL) that will not boot except in safe mode.  It gets almost all of the way through the boot then freezes with two vertical checkerboard lines and the trackpad-controlled pinwheel for a cursor.

Also, the chime works at the beginning, but after boot in ANY mode the sound preference pane says there is no sound output device.

What should I do?

Regards,

Don

Answer (score 1):

Schedule an appointment with the genius bar and bring it to them. At the very least they'll be able to run you the diagnostic tools and tell you what the problem is.

My experience is these sorts of problems usually result in a pretty expensive repair bill, unless you happen to be still covered under apple care support.

Logic board probably has some sort of damage.